# Is a derived object type from the exception declaration unexpected?

Tags: c++, exception

In C++, in the exception declaration specifier, if I declare a base class and then throw a derived class, is that an unexpected exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C++, in the exception declaration specifier, if I declare a base class and then throw a derived class, is that an unexpected exception?

No. It is allowed.

Reference: 
**C++03 15.4 Exception specifications**

**Para 6:**

> An exception-specification can include the same type more than once and can include classes that are related by inheritance, even though doing so is redundant. An exception-specification can also include the class std::bad_exception (18.6.2.1).

There is a relevant example in
**Para 8:**

```
[Example:
class X { };
class Y { };
class Z: public X { };
class W { };
void f() throw (X, Y)
{
    int n = 0;
    if (n) throw X(); // OK
    if (n) throw Z(); // also OK    <------- Example of the exact scenario you posted
    throw W(); // will call unexpected()
}
—end example]
```

---

Note that Exception specifications are considered as an experiment that failed and most compilers do not implement them correctly. So avoid(rather don't) use them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the dreaded non-answer, but please don't use exception specifications:

http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

To quote the relevant parts:

> Moral #1: Never write an exception specification.
>
> Moral #2: Except possibly an empty one, but if I were you I’d avoid even that.

The caveat to #2 is "noexcept" in C++11.